# Evitar CORS en CODEIGNITER4 con XAMPP

Tags: xampp, cors, codeigniter-4

Tengo una página web en codeigniter 4, creada utilizando Composer.
Estoy utilzando fuentes como FontAwesome, MaterialIcons, etc.

Los estilos de cada fuente (.css) tienen vínculos hacia archivos ".eot", ".woff", etc, lo normal. Lo que necesito es que la aplicación este completamente local, es por ello, que descargué esos archivos y los tengo dentro de la página, específicamente dentro de la carpeta "/public/[assets/...]".

[image: Archivos]

Cuando inicio el servidor PHP SPARK, está todo bien (o al menos eso aparenta)
Mi problema es con el XAMPP, estoy accediendo a la carpeta public desde el navegador.

"http://localhost:[numeroPuerto]/[nombreCarpetaProyecto]/public/"

Al acceder de esta manera, todos los archivos, como imágenes, hojas de estilo, o archivos js, no tienen problema, solamente los ".eot", ".woff" me dan el siguiente error.

"error de CORS", y su detalle "Error de uso compartido entre dominios MissingAllowOriginHeader". (esto me muestra las herramientas de desarrollador de mi navegador, en la pestaña RED)

[image: Error CORS]

Se que significa CORS y de que trata, eso lo trabajo también en servicios IIS con C#, Docker, etc.

Puedo configurar los navegadores para evitar la seguridad CORS, pero no es una opción válida. Entiendo que lo mas probable es una configuración en el servidor XAMPP, pero aún no la encuentro.

Agradecería mucho si alguien de la comunidad tiene alguna respuesta.
Saludos Developers.